# What's the best way to only allow a PHP file to be included?

Tags: php

I want to make sure people can't type the name of a PHP script in the URL and run it. What's the best way of doing this?

I could set a variable in the file that will be including this file, and then check that variable in the file being included, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Could you please be more clear? I really don't understand how you want a file not to be run if you point your browser to it...

Comment: Maybe if preforms functions, maybe for the sake of security, the why is irrelevant.

Comment: @Unkwntech: my confusion comes from the fact that if a file is under the webroot it should be for viewing, anything secure has to be outside it...

Comment: I have an admin.php file which, depending on a $_GET variable, include()'s one of the admin pages. This way I only have to check if they have admin access in one file.

Comment: My site is a bit strange. These files are under the webroot because I allow people to view the source code of the site.

Comment: @Jeremy: some of the answer below will give you an answer in your current environment, but I would suggest keeping scripts that should not be viewable outside the webroot. It'll pay off in terms of security and of peace of mind.

Comment: @Jeremy: I would suggest then that you leave runnable code outside the webroot and have a separate folder with the .phpc files.

Comment: To view the source code I have a special script that uses highlight_file() then does some extra formatting. I also have a file browser that lets people browse all the files that make up the site, so I'd rather have all the files under the webroot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could check the URI and see if that file is being called with `

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
```

or you could move the file outside the public folder, this is a better solution.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for, thanks... I agree that moving the file outside the public folder is usually better, but in my case It'd be better to use that $_SERVER variable.

Comment: Indeed a direct way, but code sample will help -> ````if(__FILE__ == $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {die("This file is being loaded directly");
}````

Answer (score 15):

In a few of the open source applications I've poked around in, including Joomla and PHPBB, they declare a constant in the main includes file, and then verify that constant exists in each of the includes:

```
// index.php
require_once 'includes.php';

// includes.php
define('IN_MY_PROJECT', true);
include 'myInc.php';

// myInc.php
defined('IN_MY_PROJECT') || die("No direct access, plsktnxbai");
```

Answer (score 4):

I have long kept everything except directly viewable scripts outside the web root. Then configure PHP to include your script directory in the path. A typical set up would be:

```
appdir
  include
  html
```

In the PHP config (either the global PHP config or in a `.htaccess` file in the `html` directory) add this:

```
include_path = ".:/path/to/appdir/include:/usr/share/php"
```

or (for Windows)

```
include_path = ".;c:\path\to\appdir\include;c:\php\includes"
```

Note that this line is probably already in your `php.ini` file, but may be commented out allowing the defaults to work. It might also include other paths. Be sure to keep those, as well.

If you are adding it to a .htaccess file, the format is:

```
php_value include_path .:/path/to/appdir/include:/usr/share/php
```

Finally, you can add the path programatically with something like this:

```
$parentPath = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$ourPath = $parentPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'include';

$includePath = ini_get('include_path');
$includePaths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePath);
// Put our path between 'current directory' and rest of search path
if ($includePaths[0] == '.') { 
    array_shift($includePaths);
}

array_unshift($includePaths, '.', $ourPath);
$includePath = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths);
ini_set('include_path', $includePath);
```

*(Based on working code, but modified, so untested)*

This should be run in your frontend file (e.g. `index.php`). I put it in a separate include file which, after modifying the above, can be included with something like `#include '../includes/prepPath.inc'`.

I've used all the versions I've presented here with success. The particular method used depends on preferences, and how the project will be deployed. In other words, if you can't modify `php.ini`, you obviously can't use that method

Answer (score 0):

The Zend Framework recommends you keep the files outside the web root, as Unkwntech has suggested. I'd say this is the safest and most fool proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

From a PHP Nuke module:

```
<?php
if (!eregi("modules.php", $PHP_SELF)) {
   die ("You can't access this file directly...");
}
// more code ...
?>
```

Replace modules.php with your file name, and that file cannot be called directly.

Comment: This is sorely outdated. Don't use this.

Comment: It is surely outdated, as this was from 6 years ago. Is PHPNuke still around?

Answer (score 0):

One way I've seen a lot is to create a variable that has to be present in every included file and check first thing in every include:

```
if(!isset($in_prog)){
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way is to put files you want to include inside "**/include**" folder and put access right 700 to the folder

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found this one-liner quite effective:

```
$inc = get_included_files(); if(basename(__FILE__) == basename($inc[0])) exit();
```

**get_included_files()** returns an array with the files included on the script. The first position is the root file, and the other positions are the included files.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use this code:

```
// Prevent direct access, use exclusively as include only.
if (count(get_included_files()) == 1) {
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
}
```

If php file is called directly, then only one item is in included files array.