# Test if a php include is called from a local file

Tags: php

I have a php include with one function in it, I need to ensure that it can only be executed by inclusion within a local file and not from any external source.

What is the best method of testing for this?

-thanks
-sean

UPDATE:

thanks, here is some more info,
- I can't move it outside the webroot, I'm updating an existing site
- testing for REMOTE_ADDR will always return the clients ip
- the only way I want this file called is by: include_once "sendmail.php";

Comment: From a local file, do you mean from your server only?

Comment: errmm, some code would be really usefull!

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/173144/831645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two cases of your problem:

1. File can be accessed over http with any browser. In that case you can define a CONST in your main application and then chek it in includes:

   main file:

   ```
   define('MY_APP', true);
   ```

   included file:

   ```
   if (!defined('MY_APP') || MY_APP !== true) {
     die('Access denied');
   }
   ```
2. File can be accessed via file system (from nearby virtual host for example). Than you can use SERVER_NAME and REQUEST_URI checks.

Answer (score 2):

Forget testing. Just keep the file *outside* the webroot.

If it can't be served over HTTP then it can't be used externally.

(Although, if it just contains a function, and no statements that execute automatically, then any external request is going to end up with a blank HTTP response unless the server starts serving up PHP files as plain text)

Answer (score 1):

If you always include and execute it from the same file you could make a URL check in your function.

```
function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
     if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
     $pageURL .= "://";
     if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
         $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
         $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     return $pageURL;
}


//Your included function:
function doSomething() {
    if (curPageUrl() == "http://www.yourwebsite.com/function.php") {
        ... execute code...
    }
}
```

Comment: I love it when a function is called doSomething(). it goes against every coding standard ! but who's counting ;) the rest of the answer is nice though.

Comment: Haha! Well I'm sure his function is named differently. Just using this as a reference to his original function name which we are unaware of as he didn't include a code snippet. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $_SERVER array to return the IP of the caller.

```
$callerIP = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

You can than check if the $callerIP is localhost.