# Prevent use of PHP include with image files

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

I recently had a WordPress site that contained malware code saved as a PNG file, but pulled into my template file via `@include_once('images/sidebar2.png');` which then gets interpreted as PHP.

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to figure out a way to prevent this activity. I can block PHP execution in a folder, but that doesn't help this scenario. I can also force the MIME type, but that also doesn't do it.

It is possible to restrict PHP includes to `.php` files only? Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you putting user input in include like `@include_once($_GET['include']);`?

Comment: The real question you need to ask is how was the attacker to add an `@include_once` to what I'm guessing is what you believe to be a "legitimate" php file.

Comment: Yes, the site was hacked which gave them the ability to drop code in our template. Naturally, measures were taken to clean and prevent a reoccurance.

Answer (score 2):

Just a shot from the hip : Replace all your `include_once` references in your template with `include_once_secure` and

```
function include_once_secure($fileName) {
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))=='php') {
        include_once($fileName);
    } else {
        //here you could throw an error or exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Just note that any variables that are used in the current script, won't be passed to the include file (see [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more info). The best way to ensure only certain files are being included is with LFI (Local File Inclusion) prevention (examples can be found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173144/whats-the-best-way-to-only-allow-a-php-file-to-be-included))

Comment: My problem is that the site was hacked and new code introduced. We've taken measures to prevent a reoccurance, but I'm hoping to find a way to enforce .php files only in include() statments either by configuring PHP itself or using htaccess.